# Integrating MQ explorer with PAM

Tags: ibm-mq

We installed MQ explorer version 9 in Windows servers and trying to access QM on remote host which is running on Linux server, so we want to connect to remote QM on Linux server through MQ explorer which is installed on windows Machine
so as per client requirement to access this MQ explorer we need to integrate with PAM, launch the MQ explorer from PAM and pass the credentials and it should auto fill and launch the MQ explorer.
PAM will fill credentials and it will auto launch the MQ explorer.
To integrate MQ explorer to PAM and launch from PAM we need to have specific "Process Arguments which will pass all the inputs we are passing while connecting to a remote QM" or any api to incorporate im PAM
Can you help on this requirement?
Is there any command to be executed in windows which will launch MQ explorer to connect to remote Queue manager with all the parameters that we will give in the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are merging a bunch of information together that you shouldn't be.

All MQ client applications (including MQ Explorer) should be using a UserId and Password when connecting to a queue manager and it would be a good idea to use SSL/TLS too on the connection.

The MQ client application should not / does not need to be aware of what kind of authentication the queue manager is going to perform.  i.e. Local OS, LDAP and PAM (Unix/Linux only).

How the queue manager authenticates the incoming UserId and Password is controlled by the queue manager's CONNAUTH attribute.  Currently, CONNAUTH supports Local OS, LDAP and PAM authentication.

Hence, in MQ Explorer, do the following to add your UserId and Password:

- Right click on the queue manager and select ***Connection Details*** -> ***Properties***
- Click on ***UserId*** in the left panel
- Click the ***Enable user identification*** and input your UserId and Password.
- Click the ***OK*** button to save it.

Now when you connect to that particular remote queue manager, assuming the queue manager has been setup for authentication, it will authenticate the incoming UserId and Password.

Comment: I think in this case the OP may be asking about windows Privileged Access Management not Pluggable Authentication Modules?

Comment: ?? Only Microsoft would create their own acronym of a well-known acronym!!  If that is what the OP was asking then Privileged Access Management of an Active Directory has nothing to do with MQ. PAM for AD is about protecting AD from hackers.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to start MQ Explorer automatically and start a connection defined by command line parameters.

This is not fully possible. You can start MQ Explorer with the command strmqcfg, but connection parameters are managed internally.

Comment: yes. thats right. Thats what i am looking for. So its not possible to give all the connection parameters through command ?

Comment: No, you need to create connections in MQ Explorer, or import connections created and exported previously. But you can’t do either from the command line.

Answer (score -1):

To integrate MQ explorer with QMs running on linux server, the IBM knowledge center has briefed up few things. It may be of help to you,

Procedure
Select the queue manager, QUEUE.MANAGER.1
Open the Channels folder, then right-click Client Connections > New > Client-connection Channel...
Enter the channel name, CHANNEL1, for the client connection, and click Next.
Enter the queue manager name, QUEUE.MANAGER.1
Enter the following string as the connection name:

server-address (port)

Where:
server-address is the TCP/IP host name of the server
port is the TCP/IP port number the server is listening on
Click Finish.
From the command line, set the MQCHLLIB environment variable:
Enter the following command:

export MQCHLLIB=var/mqm/qmgrs/QUEUE!MANAGER!1/@ipcc

Comment: Please provide details,  the answers on SO shouldn't just link to another website.